# Trying to return an exception error when the method requires a double

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

Bit of a coding newbie here and looking for some advice!

I have the following method - a simple weight converter for kilograms to pounds, that's part of a larger console application. The user selects what conversion scheme they want and then they enter their weight and it will convert it. I was doing some unit tests for it to get a better understanding of them and decided to add some code that will return an exception if the user enters a minus number, just to make it more robust. The code is as follows:

```
    public static double KilogramsToPounds(string weightInKilos)
    {
        //Convert parameter to a double for calculation
        double kiloWeight = Double.Parse(weightInKilos);

        //Convert Kilograms to Pounds
        double poundWeight = kiloWeight * 2.20462;
        try
        {
            if (kiloWeight < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
            else
            {
                return poundWeight;
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException argEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(argEx);
        }

        return 0;

    }
```

However, when this runs it will always return 0 because it requires a double as its return type. So you get the ArgumentOutOfRange Exception, AND a 0 because it requires a double.

I was just wondering if there was any way to basically say "**if you enter a number below 0, you get this error message, but if you enter a valid positive number, you will get the correct numerical result**"? Because it seems no matter what you will need to provide a numerical value for it to be happy as well as the error message, or else you will get a "**Not all code paths return a value**" error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note - I should add the string parameter "weightInKilos" is taken from the user's console input. The code to show the choices is in a different file, and the conversion rates are in a separate file.

Comment: Exceptions are meant to be thrown out of methods. The best examples are all of the convert methods in .NET. They throw exceptions on failure, so to handle the errors you have to put those calls in try/catch blocks.

Comment: @Logarr: Not a good example since they also provide `TryParse` methods that don't throw exceptions. They don't even handle exceptions implicitely. So i would sugest to create a `TryConvertKgToPounds` which returns a `bool` and uses an `out` parameter to return the `poundWeight`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Sorry, I was referring specifically to the `Convert` class's methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `try-catch` from your method. Just throw your exception. Your method is not supposed to catch exceptions it throws itself.

Put the `try-catch` around the call to `KilogramsToPounds`.

Comment: This worked a treat, many thanks for all responses! Working as I expected now!

Answer (score 1):

The key to this is that throwing an exception will stop execution of the function, thus getting you around the whole "Not all code paths return a value" error. For instance, this is valid:

```
public int ZeroOrError(bool error)
{
    if (error)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    else
        return 0;
}
```

even though technically you don't return a value in the first part of the `if` block.

So you just need to not catch your exception (which you shouldn't be doing anyway) and you should be good to go.